# Summarized Subquery annotation with a filter by ForeignKey outer reference

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-queryset, django-subquery

I try to code the equivalent Django query from this SQL query, but I'm stuck.
Any help is welcome.
I receive a race `id` and from this race I want to do some statistics : `nb_race` = the number of races from a Horse before the race given, `best_chrono` = best time from a Horse before the race given.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(run.id)
                FROM runner run
                INNER JOIN race
                ON run.race_id = race.id
                WHERE run.horse_id = r.horse_id
                AND race.datetime_start < rc.datetime_start 
                ) AS nb_race, 
          (SELECT min(run.chrono)
                FROM runner run
                INNER JOIN race
                ON run.race_id = race.id
                WHERE run.horse_id = r.horse_id
                AND race.datetime_start < rc.datetime_start 
                ) AS best_time
FROM runner r, race rc
WHERE r.race_id = rc.id
AND rc.id = 7890
```

Django Models:

```
class Horse(models.Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class Race(models.Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    datetime_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class Runner(models.Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    horse = models.ForeignKey(Horse, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    chrono = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Comment: You may want to consider running this query via Django's ```raw()``` functionality due to the complexity of the query.

Information on the topic can be found here on the Django website.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: I deed, but I don't understand how the " Correlated subquery" works in Django. My last attempt is this : 
```runners = Runner.objects.filter(race_id=race.id) \
        .annotate( nb_course=RawSQL( "SELECT count(runner.id) FROM runner INNER JOIN race ON race.course_id = race.id WHERE runner.horse_id = %s", (OuterRef('horse_id'))))```
I just can't access to the "horse_id " in the "Runner.objects.filter(race_id=race.id)"

Comment: Frederic, what sort of table size are you working with? As if your working with a fairly small dataset where efficiency is not so much of a concern, it might be worth extracting your primary data to python and use pandas to apply the aggregation and querying? Just a suggestion.

Comment: My db is consequent:  12 000 000  runners, 990 000 horses. And that's just 2 of more than 20 tables... around 10 GiB for the total. I don't know pandas, I will have a look.

Comment: Yeah stick with SQL. I’ll have a go at it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you Lewis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)** can be used to compile an additional queryset as subquery that depends on the main queryset and execute them together as one SQL.

```py
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Count, Min, F

# prepare a repeated expression about previous runners, but don't execute it yet
prev_run = (
    Runner.objects
    .filter(
        horse=OuterRef('horse'),
        race__datetime_start__lt=OuterRef('race__datetime_start'))
    .values('horse')
)
queryset = (
    Runner.objects
    .values('id', 'horse_id', 'race_id', 'chrono', 'race__name', 'race__datetime_start')
    .annotate(
        nb_race=Subquery(prev_run.annotate(nb_race=Count('id')).values('nb_race')),
        best_time=Subquery(prev_run.annotate(best_time=Min('chrono')).values('best_time'))
    )
)
```

Some **tricks** used here are described in the linked docs:

- Output fields of the Subquery must be restricted by `.values(...)` to one field: only the aggregated value
- A subquery must be a queryset (that is evaluated lazy and combined together), not a value (that would be evaluated immediately and fail). Therefore `.annotate()` is used in the subquery (not `.aggregate()`). That adds a `GROUP BY race.horse_id`, but is is not a problem becase there is also `WHERE race.horse_id = ...` and the "group by" will be finally ignored by an SQL optimizer in a modern database backend.

It is compiled to a query equivalent to the SQL in the example. Check the SQL:

```sql
>>> print(str(queryset.query))
SELECT ...,
  (SELECT COUNT(U0.id)
   FROM runner U0 INNER JOIN race U1 ON (U0.race_id = U1.id)
   WHERE (U0.horse_id = runner.horse_id AND U1.datetime_start < race.datetime_start)
   GROUP BY U0.horse_id
   ) AS nb_race,
   ...
FROM runner INNER JOIN race ON (runner.race_id = race.id)
```

A marginal difference is that a subquery uses some internal aliases like U0 and U1.

Comment: This is working and I like the `prev_run` approach, This greatly simplifies the rest of the code. 
Thank  you hynekcer.

Comment: If you agree I will rename your question now to make it easier searchable by other people with a similar problem.

Comment: Sure, I agree, rename the title.